# Can sys.xp_cmdshell dir return just the date of a file?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using `sys.xp_cmdshell dir <filename>` in order to get the last modified date of a file. For each file, it returns 7 rows. Among those 7 is a date and file name field. The data looks like this:

> 11/23/2015  12:14 PM                 0 New Text Document - Copy (10) - Copy.txt

The date and the file name is separated by 17 spaces. Is there a way to get just the date? I'm finding splitting to be a difficult task, so I think it'd be easier to just get the date.

Comment: Check out this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32293517/how-to-load-files-according-to-created-date-in-windows-command-shell-via-sql-ser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert your result into a temp table where the date can be parsed.

Edit: Added defensive code.

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#files') is not null
    drop table #files;
begin
    create table #files
    (
        files varchar(200)
    )

    insert into #files
    exec sys.xp_cmdshell 'dir <filename>'

    select *,
        convert(date, substring(files, 1, PATINDEX('% %', files)))
    from #files
end
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dir` like this:

```
sys.xp_cmdshell for /f %a in ('dir /b <filename.ext>') do @echo %~ta
```

It will only output the date for `<filename.ext>`.

If you want filename and date, use: `@echo %a %~ta`